# How contains? in Clojure work?

Tags: clojure, programming-languages

I came across this snippet of code in a book of Clojure. Can you please explain me how `contains?` works?

```
(contains? [1 2 3] 3)
;= false
(contains? [1 2 3] 2)
;= true
(contains? [1 2 3] 0)
;= true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at the [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/contains_q):

> **contains?**
>
> (contains? coll key)
>
> Returns true if key is present in the given collection, otherwise
>   returns false. Note that for numerically indexed collections like
>   vectors and Java arrays, this tests if the numeric key is within the
>   range of indexes. 'contains?' operates constant or logarithmic time;
>   it will not perform a linear search for a value. See also 'some'.

So, in your example, `(contains? [1 2 3] 3)` returns `false` because the collection `[1 2 3]` does not contain an item at the index `3` (that means `(get [1 2 3] 3)` would return `nil`).

Comment: so the name is a little bit confusing. Thx

Comment: @TruongHa Yeah, common mistake to think it says if a collection contains an element. Confuses everyone :-)